# Reading a Specific Line in a Text File and set it to a variable via Batch FIle

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file, where i have to read line 21 and set it in a variable. Im using the below.

```
Set Source="C\Users\file.txt"
for /f "Tokens=* delims=" %%G in ('findstr /n "^" %Source%') do (
    if %%G equ 21 (
        set Variable="%%H"
    )
)
```

Its not working. Please Help.

Comment: You could just use `for /f "usebackq skip=20 delims=" %%I in ("%source%") do set "var=%%I"`.  See `help for` in a cmd console for more info on `skip`.

Comment: Change your `Tokens` and `Delims` to `"Tokens=1* Delims=:"`. Using @rojo idea, you'd need to do it like this. `for /f "usebackq skip=20 delims=" %%I in (%source%) do if not defined var set "var=%%I"`.

Comment: Hi Compo, "Tokens=1* Delims=:*"
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "Tokens=1* delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /n "^" %Source%') do if %%G equ 21 set Variable=%%H
echo.%Variable%
```

This has my required output.

Answer (score 2):

Given that line 21 is not empty, you could do it like this:

```cmd
set "SOURCE=C\Users\file.txt"
for /F usebackq^ skip^=20^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%SOURCE%") do (
    if not defined LINE set "LINE=%%L"
)
echo(Line 21 contains "%LINE%".
```

If line 21 might be empty, you could use this instead:

```cmd
set "SOURCE=C\Users\file.txt"
for /F "usebackq skip=20 delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%SOURCE%"') do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    goto :CONTINUE
)
:CONTINUE
set "LINE=%LINE:*:=%"
echo(Line 21 contains "%LINE%".
```

And here is an alternative approach, using [input redirection `<`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
set "SOURCE=C\Users\file.txt"
< "%SOURCE%" (
    for /L %%I in (1,1,20) do set /P LINE=""
    set "LINE="
    set /P LINE=""
)
echo(Line 21 contains "%LINE%".
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But, this is not working for me.
    for /f "Tokens=1* delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /n "^" %Source%') do if %%G equ 21 set Variable=%%H                                                                                                   this above fetched me the correct results.

Answer (score -1):

<s>Use **SETX** with its **/A** option.  See **SETX /?** for more info.</s>

Okay:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %V in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /n /r /c:".*" <FILE_PATH> ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr /b /l /c:"21:"') do set LINE=%V

set LINE=%LINE:~3%
```

%V needs changing to %%V if used in a script.

Comment: How does this help the user read the file to get the correct line?  Also, I do not believe the users intent is to **permanently** set it as an environmental variable.

Comment: This is a low quality response with no relevance to the question posed.

Comment: And what if the user wants to use that variable within the current batch file?  RTM Note 2.   And as I said previously it does not sound like they want to permanently set the variable to the system which is what SETX does. RTM Note 1.